# How to launch application under test for every test case without creating the new session for winappdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium, winappdriver

I am automating a windows application in Java using winappdriver where I have three test cases and each test needs to launch the application. I am using below code to initialize the driver and launch the application.

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
capabilities.setCapability("app, "appPath");
capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "windows");
capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "windowsPC");
capabilities.setCapability("appWorkingDir", "XXXXXXXX");
driver = new WindowsDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), capabilities);
```

To launch the application for each test I need to run the above code before every test case. This will result in the initialization of the driver three times. Though my tests are passing but getting below messages in Eclipse console window. Note: I am starting the winappdriver programmatically. Just want to know what is the best way to handle this situation.

[Eclipse Console Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/64vI1.png)

Answer (score 0):

How about using the [desktop session](https://github.com/microsoft/WinAppDriver/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#general-development--best-practices) and launch your application under test from there. In this session, you can launch your application under test as many times you want to, without having to restart WinAppDriver every time.

Or you could call your tests within another test, so test finalisation only happens when the calling test is finished.

Something like this (warning: pseudo-code in C#):

```
[TestMethod]    
public void MainTest()
{
     TestA();
     TestB();
     TestC();
}
```